# Local storage saving every input and checkbox value on a page

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Is there a way to save every input field and checkbox without much code? I have this and it's working great to save separate input fields, with a `class="stored"` on each:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function init() {
        if (localStorage["fname"]) {
            $('#fname').val(localStorage["fname"]);
        }
    }
    init();
});

$('.stored').change(function () {
    localStorage[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});

<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="label_fn control-label" for="fname">First name (required):</label>
    <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_fn form-control stored">
    </div>
```

But is there a way to, say, set a class of `"something-container"` on the container div and using this script as a base, save all input fields to storage and have them remain populated in the fields until the user clears the session?

Comment: @CodeiSir That helped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply change your selector in the `change` event from `".stored"` to `".something-container input"`.  In the `Init` method you'll want to do something like this:

```
$(".something-container input").each(function () {
    $(this).val(localStorage[$(this).attr("name")])
}
```

A side note, the `.change` binding should likely get done inside the `$(document).ready` method as well.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong or it's not working. I tried:

`$(document).ready(function () {
    function init() {
  $(".something-container input").each(function () {
   $(this).val(localStorage[$(this).attr("name")])
  } 
    }
 init();
});`

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, but here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/za7ekgyz